# How do I turn on the Alexa "Audio Player" interface from the serverless.yml file with the serverless framework?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, serverless, alexa-voice-service, aws-serverless

I am trying to build an Alexa skill with the serverless framework for AWS.  https://serverless.com

Does anyone know how to turn on the Alexa "Audio Player" interface from the serverless.yml file?

I can currently add intents but I can't find any documentation on how to add the "Audio Player" interface.

If I turn on the "Audio Player" interface from the Alexa console, when I deploy my serverless code, it turns it off.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to edit the custom / alexa / skills area of your serverless.yml file.  Here is a sample of what it should look like.

```
custom:
  alexa:
    skills:
      - id: 
        manifest:
          publishingInformation:
            locales:
              en-US:
                name: testingServerlesssl
          apis:
            custom:
              endpoint:
                uri: 
              interfaces:
                - type: AUDIO_PLAYER
          manifestVersion: '1.0'
```

In general, you can make changes in the Alexa Dashboard and then run

```
sls alexa manifests
```

which will show you the changes.  Then you can find where that area is in the serverless.yml file and cut and paste to make those changes permanent.